# I want to use variables in cells (). formula

Tags: vba, visio

Shape.Cells ("something"). Formula = XXX
I want to enter a variable on VBA with

In Cells.Formula which is different from the file that starts VBA
I want to enter the value of a variable defined in VBA (here, the string "1.0.0")

Code only for the relevant part

```
Sub Input_Version_Information(ByVal VSSXpath As String)
    version_str =  "1.0.0"        
    For Each vssxMaster In vssxMasters
        vssxMaster.Shapes.Item(1).Cells("Prop.Version").Formula = version_str                
    Next
End Sub
```

All code

```
Sub Input_Version_Information(ByVal VSSXpath As String)
    Dim vsoApp As Visio.Application    
    Dim vssxDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim vssxMasters As Visio.Masters
    Dim vssxMaster As Visio.Master
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim version_str As String        
    Set vsoApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VSSXpath, visOpenRW)
    Set vssxDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(1)
    Set vssxMasters = vssxDoc.Masters    
    FileName = Dir(VSSXpath)
    FileName = Replace(FileName, ".vssx", "")    
    version_str = Mid(FileName, InStr(FileName, "v") + 1, Len(FileName))
        
    For Each vssxMaster In vssxMasters
        vssxMaster.Shapes.Item(1).Cells("Prop.Version").Formula = version_str                
    Next
    
    vssxDoc.Save    
    vssxDoc.Close
    vsoApp.Quit

    End Sub

Sub test_update()
    test_vssx_file = ”Flowchart_v1.0.0.vssx"
    Call Input_Version_Information(test_vssx_file)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need use cell value as string you must use syntax

```
vssxMaster.Shapes.Item(1).Cells("Prop.Version").Formula = chr(34) & version_str & chr(34)
```

Or triple quotes

```
vssxMaster.Shapes.Item(1).Cells("Prop.Version").Formula = """7.40"""
```

**PS** [Topic with same question](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=8832.0), sorry i cant find today hyperlinks from M$FT official resources…